# read a specific number of characters in the text file using fread and fseek

Tags: c

Let's say I have a text file like this

> This is a text file which contains some numbers.

So I want to use fseek and fread to read some parts of the text file.
For example, from position 0 to 13, I'll get "This is a text". 
Then from position 14 to 24, I'll get " file which", then from position 25 to the end of file, I'll get " contains some numbers."

I've tried to use fseek and fread but I've got some additional weird characters like "This is a text?"

My attempt to use fseek and fread:

```
src = fopen(textfile, "r");
int chunksize = data[i].end - data[i].start;
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(chunksize));

seek(src, data[i].start, SEEK_SET);
fread(buffer, 1, chunksize, src);
fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
```

where `data[i].start` is the start position to read to part and `data[i].end` is the end position to stop. For example, from 14 to 24, I'll get " file which". start is 14 and end is 25.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(chunksize))` is an error - `sizeof(chunksize) == sizeof(int)` is a compile-time constant. Drop the `sizeof`. You'll need to show the code you use to display the data, and (hint) how you're null-terminating it.

Comment: And, in addition to Mat's comments, provide the input file you are using.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite your code approximately as follows:

```
src = fopen(textfile, "r");
int chunksize = ...
char *buffer = malloc(chunksize + 1);
fseek(src, data[i].start, src);
int len = fread(buffer, 1, chunksize, src);
*(buffer+len) = '\0';
```

So, we have the following, a buffer containing what was read from the file.  We have a string terminator following the content read (which may be less than you asked for).  If you now issue:

```
print("%s\n", buffer)
```

You will get exactly what you read from the file.

PS: It is a good idea to check the return from the `fopen()` to be sure that the file opened properly, and the return from `malloc()` to ensure that memory was allocated successfully, and the return from `fread()` to ensure that the correct amount of data was read.

Answer (score 0):

Random characters after the end of the data arise from not null terminating the input string, or not limiting the output to the data that was read.  `fread()` does not 'null terminate' what it reads; it would be useless if it did.

You are allocating too little memory.  You have:

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(chunksize));
```

You need:

```
char *buffer = malloc(chunksize);
```

Or you could allocate an extra byte and store a null byte `'\0'` in that.  If you're going to need to pass it to code that needs a string, this is better:

```
char *buffer = malloc(chunksize + 1);
```

You should be checking the error returns of most functions; specifically, you should be paying attention to `malloc()`, `fopen()` and `fread()`.  You also need to use `fseek()`, not `seek()`.

You might use:

```
src = fopen(textfile, "r");
if (src == 0)
    err_exit("Failed to open %s for reading\n", textfile);

int chunksize = data[i].end - data[i].start;
char *buffer = malloc(chunksize + 1);
if (buffer == 0)
    err_exit("Failed to allocate %d bytes memory\n", chunksize);

fseek(src, data[i].start, SEEK_SET);
size_t nbytes = fread(buffer, 1, chunksize, src);
fseek(src, 0, SEEK_SET);
buffer[nbytes] = '\0';
if (nbytes != 0)
    printf("Read: <<%.*s>>\n", (int)nbytes, buffer);
```

or:

```
    prinf("Read: <<%s>>\n", buffer);
```

Comment: Is not `fseek()` in a text file UB unless seeking from the beginning or a previous `ftell()`?

Comment: If you're on Windows; yes (at least in theory).  If you're on a sane system; no.  The issue is CRLF to NL mappings; you might seek to the middle of a CRLF pair, or something.  I'm not sure whether there's a real problem on any actual system — do you have a counter-example?

Comment: Did not find that reference to Windows in C11 7.21.9.2 4 "For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file and whence shall be SEEK_SET."

Comment: That's what the C standard says.  The POSIX standard for [`fseek()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html) overrides the C standard (on systems that pay passing attention to the POSIX standard). It has caveats about wide-char streams, but not about text vs binary since POSIX doesn't recognize the difference.

Comment: I used the C standard here rather than the POSIX standard as OP's post appeared to be generic C and no tag nor mention of being POSIX.

Comment: Fine; I don't like that bit of the C standard.  You're welcome to abide by it if you wish, but it isn't relevant to me.  The issue has been brought out into the open.  It most likely won't actually affect the OP, but, as I said, if you're on Windows, then in theory it might affect you and otherwise, it won't.